# Browser debugging openlayers in vscode

Tags: debugging, vite, openlayers

I'd like to step through the code of main.js file as shown in a simple openlayers web map found here:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/accessible.html

I'm using the latest version of ol (8.1.0). From what I understand, openlayers uses vite. When I run `npm start`, the webpage displays fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAgYW.png)

To debug the "application" running in the browser using vscode, I tried `npm run dev`. This launches the webmap fine. The launch.json file looks as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge",
            "url": "http://localhost:5173",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried setting a breakpoint in my main.js file but I keep getting the unbound symbol error in vscode. It reads:

> Unbound breakpoint
>
> Some of your breakpoints could not be set. If you're having an issue, you can troubleshoot your launch configuration.

I looked around a bit on the web and also added the following in package.json file under scripts element:

```
"dev": "vite --port 5173"
```

When I check out the troubleshooting assistance in vscode, it reads the following (path prefix omitted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOANn.png)

I tried removing the webRoot line from launch.json. I also tried changing the webRoot to the following with no luck:

`${workspaceFolder}/src ${workspaceFolder}/main.js ${workspaceFolder}/index.html`

I don't quite follow this whole process of how the debugging is configured. I was just hoping to be able to learn openlayers by setting it up as described and later on being able to debug through the source.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks a bunch again.